# Creating a user in Oracle Active Data Guard

Tags: oracle, administration, dataguard

Our database uses Active Data Guard.

If I create a user in primary database, will that be automatically created in DR database ?

Comment: What did your own testing reveal?

Comment: Re-phrasing the question - "does every activity on primary gets replicated on DR". Want to proactively understand what does and what does not gets replicated. Alternatively - is there a document which gives this information.

Answer (score 0):

the DR is maintained by applying all of the redo that is generated on the primary. Thus all activity on the primary should be replicated on the DR.  It wouldn't make much sense if the DR were not kept as a mirror copy of the primary, would it?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: **Yes**, the user you created in the PD will be created in the ADG.

An oracle ADG is a physical standby which enables read-only access while Redo Apply is active.

There are three types of standby database in Oracle.

1. Physical standby - Apply changes through `Redo` (actually it's block-level-copy)
2. Logically standby - Apply changes through SQL statements (exacted automatically by `LogMiner`).
3. Snapshot standby - Receive and archive, not apply.

An Active Data Guard is a physical standby.